# Pandas pd.to_datetime only keep time do not date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe(Pandas), with a column representing dates, in the following format:

```
import pandas as pd
import tushare as ts

data = ts.get_tick_data('600030',date='2019-06-28',src='tt') [['time','price','change','volume','amount']]
print(data.head())
```

Specifically, I would like to use pd.to_datetime convert the 'time' column to datetime.

The code are:

```
  import pandas as pd
  import tushare as ts

  data = ts.get_tick_data('600030',date='2019-06-28',src='tt') [['time','price','change','volume','amount']]
  data.index=pd.to_datetime(data['time'])
  del data['time']
  print(data.head())
```

The results are as follow:

```
                           price  change  volume    amount
   time                                                
   2019-06-29 09:25:04  23.85   -0.07    6825  16279485
   2019-06-29 09:30:02  23.85    0.00    2736   6529832
   2019-06-29 09:30:05  23.85    0.00    3964   9459955
   2019-06-29 09:30:08  23.85    0.00     665   1585346
   2019-06-29 09:30:11  23.87    0.02     348    830136
```

I only want the time with the datetime style but do not the date.
Like this:

```
          price  change  volume    amount
time                                     
09:25:04  23.85   -0.07    6825  16279485
09:30:02  23.85    0.00    2736   6529832
09:30:05  23.85    0.00    3964   9459955
09:30:08  23.85    0.00     665   1585346
09:30:11  23.87    0.02     348    830136
```

So I need the the help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'date':['2019-06-29 09:25:04','2019-06-29 09:30:02'],
                       'col2':[2,3]})

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.time
```

if you want to make this as index then just do

```
df.set_index('time',inplace=True)
```

Comment: just do df.set_index('time',inplace=True)

Comment: @anky_91 I have updated the code and thanks for the feedback

Comment: @XYXUE do a `df.reset_index(inplace=True)` before doing any of the other stuff.

Comment: @tawab_shakeel I use your code but  I can not get the results which I want.

Comment: @XYXUE what issue you are facing ?

Comment: @tawab_shakeel
`import pandas as pd
 import tushare as ts

 data = ts.get_tick_data('600030',date='2019-06-28',src='tt')[['time','price','change','volume','amount']]
 data.set_index(data['time'],inplace=True)
 data.index=pd.to_datetime(data['time'])

 df = pd.DataFrame(data={'date':['2019-06-29 09:25:04','2019-06-29 09:30:02'],'col2':[2,3]})

 df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.time
 print(df.head())`

Comment: @tawab_shakeel 
The results are:
`                    date  col2      time
 0  2019-06-29 09:25:04     2  09:25:04
 1  2019-06-29 09:30:02     3  09:30:02`

Comment: @tawab_shakeel 
And they are not what I want.
I want the results are:
` price  change  volume    amount
 time                                     
 09:25:04  23.85   -0.07    6825  16279485
 09:30:02  23.85    0.00    2736   6529832
 09:30:05  23.85    0.00    3964   9459955
 09:30:08  23.85    0.00     665   1585346
 09:30:11  23.87    0.02     348    830136`

Comment: @XYXUE the dataframe i am using is just  an example you have to apply on your dataframe column

Comment: @Sid
Sorry I can not understand your meaning? Can you show your code?
Thank you.

Comment: try

```data.reset_index(inplace=True)
data['time']= pd.to_datetime(data['date']).dt.time
data.set_index('time',inplace=True)```

Comment: @tawab_shakeel  Thank you very much. It make it. I can not paste the whole code in the comment.

Comment: @XYXUE you welcome ,Approve the post so that more people can benefit from this post

Comment: @tawab_shakeel I have clicked the accpet,thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I should write this answer in the comment, but I can not find how to paste my code in the comment with the proper format.
I found this answer on  Google：
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74784/how-do-i-add-code-while-writing-comments

Thankyou for @tawab_shakeel, with their help I've solved this problem.
The code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import tushare as ts

data = ts.get_tick_data('600030',date='2019-06-28',src='tt'[['time','price','change','volume','amount']]
data.set_index(data['time'],inplace=True)
data.index=pd.to_datetime(data['time']).dt.time
del data['time']

# data = pd.DataFrame(data={'date':['2019-06-29 09:25:04','2019-06-29 09:30:02'],
#                        'col2':[2,3]})

# data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date']).dt.time

print(data.head())
```