# How to use just the time part of a datetime in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using some date and time variables, but I only want to use the time part.

For example, a certain column A and B when I do'dtypes', it shows "dtype('O')" in both, but the output for A is:

```
0        2017-11-29 17:14:00
1        2017-02-15 15:35:00
2        2018-10-18 08:02:00
3        2017-06-22 09:25:00
```

And for B is:

```
0        2017-11-29 20:00:00
1        2017-02-15 16:43:00
2        2018-10-18 11:08:00
3        2017-06-22 11:29:00
```

Then I do this:

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
df = df[df['A'].apply(lambda v: isinstance(v, datetime))] 
df = df[df['B'].apply(lambda v: isinstance(v, datetime))]
```

However, what I want to do is to subtract the time of A and B. Only the time, not the date.

For example, when I do df['A']-df['B'], I just want the output of the first line to be 02:46. Also, how can I transform this into minutes, but as an integer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas pd.to\_datetime only keep time do not date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56816833/pandas-pd-to-datetime-only-keep-time-do-not-date)

Comment: have you tried using `.time()` method to get the `time` from the `datetime` and then subtract those ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the shape of your dataframe :

```
                    A                   B
0 2017-11-29 17:14:00 2017-11-29 20:00:00
1 2017-02-15 15:35:00 2017-02-15 16:43:00
2 2018-10-18 08:02:00 2018-10-18 11:08:00
3 2017-06-22 09:25:00 2017-06-22 11:29:00
```

then all you need to do is create a datetime object then you apply your operation to it

```
df[['A','B']] = df[['A','B']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

df['B'] - df['A']

0   02:46:00
1   01:08:00
2   03:06:00
3   02:04:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

another method using `pd.to_timedelta` and `np.timedelta64` assuming that both columns are already datetimes.

```
   df['diff'] = abs(
    pd.to_timedelta(df["A"].dt.time.astype(str), "h")
    - pd.to_timedelta(df["B"].dt.time.astype(str), "h")
) / np.timedelta64(1, "h")
```

---

```
print(df)
                   A                   B      diff
0 2017-11-29 17:14:00 2017-11-29 20:00:00  2.766667
1 2017-02-15 15:35:00 2017-02-15 16:43:00  1.133333
2 2018-10-18 08:02:00 2018-10-18 11:08:00  3.100000
3 2017-06-22 09:25:00 2017-06-22 11:29:00  2.066667
```

or

```
(
    pd.to_timedelta(df["A"].dt.time.astype(str), "h")
    - pd.to_timedelta(df["B"].dt.time.astype(str), "h")
) 

0   -1 days +21:14:00
1   -1 days +22:52:00
2   -1 days +20:54:00
3   -1 days +21:56:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: This is tricky, because in your example `B > A`, but try `A - B` and you get wrong output.

Comment: Also, OP only wanted to subtract the time.  Your answer, if the dates are different, will also subtract the dates.

Comment: you are right, let me edit @Erfan r.ook

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. I'm just curious about something. if you are dealing with numbers, ou "timedelta/datetime", why does it work when you do astype(str)? Why is string?

Comment: @bonaqua under the hood a date time is just a number, the `to_datetime` and `to_timedelta` work by converting string representation of dates and times into numbers, as we needed only the time element of your data, we extract that, make sure it's a string and not a datetime object and convert it into a time delta. we then perform math based on your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround would be to subtract the date to each datetime to ensure you're only comparing times, and then subtract:

```
(df.A - df.A.dt.floor('d')) - (df.B - df.B.dt.floor('d'))

0   -1 days +21:14:00
1   -1 days +22:52:00
2   -1 days +20:54:00
3   -1 days +21:56:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
pd.to_timedelta(df[['A', 'B']].astype('datetime64').diff(axis=1)['B'].dt.seconds * 10 ** 9)

# 0   02:46:00
# 1   01:08:00
# 2   03:06:00
# 3   02:04:00
# Name: B, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

This extracts the `seconds` portion of the `timedelta` object and convert it back to a `timedelta` after factoring in the `nanoseconds`.

Or, if you only care up to the seconds:

```
pd.to_timedelta(df[['A', 'B']].astype('datetime64').diff(axis=1)['B'].dt.seconds, 's')
```

To explain, the steps taken were to:

1. Handle the `dtype('O')` and convert to `datetime64` object
2. Calculate the difference of `A` and `B` based on `axis=1`
3. Extract the difference from resulting column `B`
4. Extract the `timedelta` `seconds` (removing any days, months, etc)
5. Convert the `seconds` back to `timedelta` object.

Answer (score 1):

> subtract the time of A and B. Only the time, not the date.

```
>>> a
0   2017-11-29 17:14:00
1   2017-02-15 15:35:00
2   2018-10-18 08:02:00
3   2017-06-22 09:25:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>> b
0   2017-11-29 20:00:00
1   2017-02-15 16:43:00
2   2018-10-18 11:08:00
3   2017-06-22 11:29:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Subtract the seconds since midnight

```
>>> a1 = (a.dt.hour * 3600) + (a.dt.minute * 60) + (a.dt.microsecond / 1000000)
>>> b1 = (b.dt.hour * 3600) + (b.dt.minute * 60) + (b.dt.microsecond / 1000000)
>>> b1-a1
0     9960.0
1     4080.0
2    11160.0
3     7440.0
dtype: float64
```

Convert to a `timedelta`

```
>>> pd.to_timedelta(b1-a1, unit='S')
0   02:46:00
1   01:08:00
2   03:06:00
3   02:04:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
>>>
```

---

[.dt accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html#dt-accessor)

---

```
>>> a2 = pd.DataFrame({'hr':a.dt.hour,'min':a.dt.minute,'microsec':a.dt.microsecond})
>>> b2 = pd.DataFrame({'hr':b.dt.hour,'min':b.dt.minute,'microsec':b.dt.microsecond})
>>> b2-a2
   hr  min  microsec
0   3  -14         0
1   1    8         0
2   3    6         0
3   2    4         0
>>> c = b2-a2
>>> pd.to_timedelta(c['hr'],'hours') + pd.to_timedelta(c['min'],'minutes') + pd.to_timedelta(c['microsec'],'microseconds')
0   02:46:00
1   01:08:00
2   03:06:00
3   02:04:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```