# Pandas Format time Nanoseconds

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a problem with formatting a time series in a pandas dataframe.

```
00:18:41.728.560.640
```

is my time object.
It is hour:min:sec:ms:us:ns.

My approach was:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format="%H:%M:%S.%f")
```

Results in:

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: .560.640
```

But this is only working for milliseconds.
Is there another way to format the time or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datetime struggles with the dots separating ms, us and ns. You can remove them with regex:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'].replace(r'(?<!:\d\d)\.', '', regex=True), format="%H:%M:%S.%f")
```

We use a negative lookbehind `(?<!:\d\d)` to make sure the first dot isn't replaced by an empty string.

Comment: Thank you! This works fine. How can I disable the date to plot it?
1900-01-01 00:18:41.728560640 --> 00:18:41.728560640

Comment: use [dt.time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56816898/13525512)

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be:

```
pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'].str[::-1].str.replace('.', '', 2).str[::-1])
```

```
                          0
0 0 days 00:18:41.728560640
```